# Can still access a control's properties after it is disposed

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, using

I am using the following template below to show a modal form

```
Using tempForm As New CustomForm

    'Do Something

    StaticClass.StaticMemeber = tempForm
    tempForm.ShowDialog

End Using

'I can still access the properties of tempForm here
MsgBox(StaticClass.StaticMemeber.Text)

'However this below returns True
MsgBox(StaticClass.StaticMember.IsDisposed)


Public Class StaticClass

    Public Shared StaticMember as Control

End Class
```

Could someone help me understand why this is happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object that has been disposed still exists until the Garbage Collector deletes and frees the memory it is using. The IDispose interface is simply a pattern. One of the things that a object that implements that pattern should do is return an ObjectDisposed exeception for properties and methods after it has been disposed. However, nothing in the compiler or CLR forces an object to do that, its simply a pattern that the programmer that  coded the object should implement. Until the garbage collector actualy deletes the obejct you can still access its properties. In this case the StaticMember still references the object. The GarabageCollector will not kill the object until that reference is released.

Comment: So when I initialize an object in a using block, does the GC not kill the object eventually even though a static member from another class is still holding a reference to it?

Comment: As long as the staic member from another class holds a reference to it, the object will never be garbage collected during the normal run of the program. It will eventual be "collected" with everyhting else when the process terminates. All the using block does is gurantee that the Dispose method on the object will be called on exiting the using block, even if an exception is thrown in the using block. Its up to the object to release any unmanged or managed resource in the dispose method. The object does not destroy itself during the dispose call. Only the gc can do that.